# Compare time in ASP/VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, time, compare

I have 2 columns, one for start-time and the other for the end-time. They both are of the type `nvarchar` so that i can compare them.

I have a text box that will receive time from the user and will post-back automatically to check if the the time is valid or not.

```
Dim compared_time_1 As DateTime
    Dim compared_time_2 As DateTime

    Dim select_time As SqlCommand
    select_time = New SqlCommand("select Start_Time , End_Time from Clinic_Schedule where Schedule_no = @sch_no", appt_DB_1)
    select_time.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sch_no", Sch_no)

    Dim time_rdr As SqlDataReader
    time_rdr = select_time.ExecuteReader()

    While time_rdr.Read
        compared_time_1 = DateTime.Parse(start_time_1)
        compared_time_2 = DateTime.Parse(end_time_1)
        start_time_1 = time_rdr(0).ToString
        end_time_1 = time_rdr(1).ToString




        If appt_time_txt0.Text >= start_time_1 And appt_time_txt0.Text <= end_time_1 Then
            date_valid_lbl0.Visible = True
            date_valid_lbl0.Text = "*Valid Time"

        Else
            time_valid_lbl0.Visible = True
            time_valid_lbl0.Text = "*Not Valid Time"
        End If


    End While
    time_rdr.Close()
```

I don't know if i have a problem with my logic XD.
the data filled in thoses columns are in this format : `00:00AM or 00:00PM.`
I will appreciate your help .. thanks

Comment: Any reason why you aren't storing Start_Time and End_Time as a date in Clinic_Schedule? Which backend database are you using?

Comment: What are you trying to do in these lines..? `compared_time_1 = DateTime.Parse(start_time_1)
        compared_time_2 = DateTime.Parse(end_time_1)
        start_time_1 = time_rdr(0).ToString
        end_time_1 = time_rdr(1).ToString`

Comment: Why did you say this was ASP?

Comment: My mistake... I see John has corrected the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are comparing a string against a date datatype.

Ensure that you are converting both into date datatype as follows.
Note the space between the seconds and 'AM'.

```
time1=CDate("3:19:40 AM")
time2=CDate("3:10:40 AM")
```

Then perform comparisms as follows:

```
if time1>time2 then
   'logic 
end if
```

Comment: Sure, that would be it if this were asp

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're doing the parse before loading the data from your reader.

```
compared_time_1 = DateTime.Parse(start_time_1)
compared_time_2 = DateTime.Parse(end_time_1)
start_time_1 = time_rdr(0).ToString
end_time_1 = time_rdr(1).ToString
```

should be

```
start_time_1 = time_rdr(0).ToString
end_time_1 = time_rdr(1).ToString
compared_time_1 = DateTime.Parse(start_time_1)
compared_time_2 = DateTime.Parse(end_time_1)
```

But I would even do it differently than that.  If you're trying to tell if the times are valid, you can use the datetime TryParse method.  Perhaps a bit of refactoring might also help you.  Finally, just be aware that comparing times might be problematic if there is ever a chance that schedule item might begin before midnight and end after midnight the next day.

```
Sub ReadingData()

   'initializing reader stuff here...

    Dim dtStart As DateTime, dtEnd As DateTime
    If DateTime.TryParse(time_rdr(0).ToString, dtStart) = False Then
        HandleInvalidTime()
    End If

    If DateTime.TryParse(time_rdr(1).ToString, dtEnd) = False Then
        HandleInvalidTime()
    End If

   'Closing out reader stuff here...

    HandleValidTime(dtStart, dtEnd)

End Sub

Sub HandleValidTime(TheStartTime As DateTime, TheEndTime As DateTime)
    'Do Stuff
End Sub

Sub HandleInvalidTime()
    'Do Stuff
End Sub
```